# prepareForSegue method works every other time

Tags: ios, tableview, uistoryboard

I'm passing location_id from the LocationTableViewController to the BeerTableViewController using the prepareForSegue method to get a locations beer results when a location cell is tapped. My problem is that the location_id is only updated every other time.

Example: When tapping location 1, it loads the beers for that location. Then I hit the back button and tap location 2, but it still loads the location 1 beers. If I hit back again, then tap location 2 again, it does display the correct location 2 beers.

Why does it take two attempts to load the correct location_id?

```
LocationTableViewController.m

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    self.selected_location = indexPath.row;
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"beer"]){
        BeerTableViewController *beer = (BeerTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        Location *location = [self.location_results objectAtIndex:self.selected_location];
        beer.location_id = location.location_id;
        }
}
```

Then in the BeerTableViewController I use the location_id to get results

```
BeerTableViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"locations/%@/beers.json", self.location_id];

    [[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:path parameters:nil
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                                            NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
                                            NSMutableArray *beer_results = [NSMutableArray array];
                                            for (id beerDictionary in response) {
                                                Beer *beer = [[Beer alloc] initWithDictionary:beerDictionary];
                                                [beer_results addObject:beer];

                                            }
                                            self.beer_results = beer_results;
                                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                                        }
                                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Error fetching beers!");
                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                        }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will be called *after* `prepareForSegue:sender:`, so you are setting the `self.selected_location` to the correct row *after* you set `location_id` on the beer view controller.

This is why you see the right row the next time around. You beer view controller always lags one row behind.

In your `prepareForSegue:sender:`, if you have a reference to the UITableView, you can just get the current correct selected row from the table view directly.

Assuming you have a @property 'tableView' in your `LocationTableViewController`, you can use `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]`

**EDIT**

If your `LocationTableViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, then you already have this @property `tableView`. In that case, your `prepareForSegue:sender:` would just looks like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"beer"]){

      BeerTableViewController *beer = (BeerTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
      NSInteger selectedRow = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
      Location *location = [self.location_results objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
      beer.location_id = location.location_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but how do I get the correct selected row in prepareForSegue:sender:

Comment: See my edit from a minute ago. Basically you can use the method `-[UITableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` assuming you have a @property that points to your table view.

Comment: I don't have a @property that points to the table view. When I added it, I get a warning and it hides the instance variable of tableView causing no locations to load when building. Any ideas?

Comment: If your LocationTableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController, then you already have a @property called `tableView`. No need to add another one.

Comment: Thanks @Firoze Lafeer, that was it.